# img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: reactjs, tags, element, children

I get the error "*img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML*`." I also try with the self-closing tag </> but it doesn't work either

This is my code App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import images from "./api-mock.json";

function App() {
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState(images.resources);
  return (
    <div className="image-grid">
      {" "}
      {imageList.map((image) => (
        <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id}>
          {" "}
        </img>
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just as the error says - you put a child node in the `<img>` when you shouldn't. Change

```
    <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id}>
      {" "}
    </img>
```

to

```
    <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id} />
```

Comment: Yah i have tried but that didn't work either

Comment: It should make the error you described in your question go away. Does a different error appear? Are you sure you saved the changes?

Comment: Oh yah i tried again, the void element error disappear but there's new mistake at line 11 which is "unexpected token, excepted "," "

Comment: It means you made a typo somewhere, but the code in your question is syntactically correct, and the code in my answer is also syntactically correct. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to say what the problem is - it's also an entirely different question from your original question.