# Display an array of image Reactjs Firebase SDK 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am quite new to Reactjs and Firebase. Now im trying to display an array of image that fetching from a selected document ID in Firestore Web SDK9.
For example, I have an array of image like the following figure below:

[image: An array of image]

I want to display all the image with url link in "imgUrls" field. At the first time, I let user choose their options with an unique ID and link it to the new page that contains all the information with that ID. Here is my code:

```
<Link to={`/view/${currentItem.id}`}>
    {currentItem.data.dateCreate}
</Link>
```

Then, I fetched all the data related to this ID:

```
useEffect(() => {
     const fetchDocById = async () => {
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
           
           setUser({
              ...docSnap.data()
        })
        ;
        } else {
           setUser({});
        }
  }
     fetchDocById()}, [id]);
```

Then, I display all the information related to this ID, for example:

```
<p>Creator: {user.creator}</p>
<p>Creation Date: {user.dateCreate}</p>
```

These line of codes are working very well. However , I have an issue with displaying the image's dataset. I have try to use: `<img src={user.imgUrls}></img>`. This code worked with the array of only one item on this. If the array is more than one, it displayed nothing. I had took the picture of this error:

[image: error]

Besides this, I have tried to mapping the array by using:

```
<div>
   { user.imgUrls.map((url) => (<img src={url}> </img>)) }
</div>
```

But it said that **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**.

Could you please try to help me in this issues. I really do appreciate that.
Thank you so much!

Comment: In case the document doesn't exist, or when the web app first loads, imgUrls is undefined. Try using [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `{ user.imgUrls?.map((url) => (<img src={url}> </img>)) }` (the `?` after imgUrls)

Comment: Pretty sure you had asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455312) earlier and this error was part of it.  Please don't delete past questions especially when someone has answered that and resolved original issue.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have tried your solution but it said that:"img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.". And thank you for the advice. I deleted the old post since I just want to make a question clearer. But, thank you so much for you help and support

Comment: Try just `<img src={url} />` and not `<img src={url}> </img>` in the map just mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69055325/13130697).

Comment: @Dharmaraj it worked now. Thank you so much bro. I really do appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is executed after the initial render of the component. You may have initialized user state with `{}`. So, when the component is rendered for the first time, `user.imgUrls` is `undefined`, cause there is no property named `imgUrls` in user object. And `undefined` doesn't have any function called `map`. That's why the error was shown.
You can solve it in many ways. But what's common in each approach is that don't call `map` function until `user` has a property called `imgUrls`.

```
Solution 1:using logical operator
<div>
   {Array.isArray(user.imgUrls) && user.imgUrls.map((url) => (<img src={url}> </img>)) }
</div>

Solution 2:using ternary operator
<div>
   {Array.isArray(user.imgUrls) ? user.imgUrls.map((url) => (<img src={url}> </img>)):null }
</div>

Solution 3:using optional chaining 
<div>
   {user.imgUrls?.map((url) => (<img src={url}> </img>)) }
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think solution 3 is worked for me and just edit (<img src={url}> </img>)) to <img src={url} /> like @Dharmaraj have mentioned above.